# OSX Layout positioning from code cause wrong position

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-yosemite, appkit

I have a problem with positioning NSViews on screen from code inside my app.

Orientation system on Mac is like in math, so 0,0 is in bottom left corner.

So, if you want to position your View on top left corner, it frame origin should be `0,height_of_window/parentView`. Here starts my problems.

My window have size `NSRect (x=0, y=0), (width=643, height=469)`
I want to position my custom view in top left corner so I use:

```
NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, superviewRect.size.height, 329, 214);
```

to reach top of my screen but nothing shows up. The view is drawn outside windows' bounds. But when I aim with some smaller number like this:

```
NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 200, 329, 214);
```

My View shows up like this:
[image]

And it is placed somewhere, not at the top but at least i can see it. 
How I can measure this top left corner from code to place it in the right place, when window got resized or similar case? I have Retina display, this is causing my bad calculations?

I hope you can understand what I menat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the coordinate system has `(0,0)` in bottom left corner.

This means that bounds of the inner view are relative to the bottom left corner of the view itself. So you should subtract the height of the internal component from the total height to find the correct position. So:

```
NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, superviewRect.size.height - 214, 329, 214);
```

You should really consider reading the View programming guide, especially [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH10-SW8) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH4-SW2).

Mind that you can flip the coordinate system by overriding `isFlipped` for the parent view, so that everything is interpreted with `(0,0)` in top left corner.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was really confused. When I was trying to do something in iOS, top left corner is `(0,0)`. Why there is inconsistency between this two platforms?

Comment: Hi, I have another question. How to set scrollView document view to be pinned to top left corner? If scrollView is big enough/bigger than its content, everything is drawn from bottom to up and it not looks right. I have to oferride isFlipped of scrollView?